# Strip all styling from pasted text in DraftJS?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

When pasting text from word or another source into draftjs the formatting comes along for the ride, I tried stripping the styling data like so:

```
onChange={(newEditorState) => {
                        const raw = convertToRaw(newEditorState.getCurrentContent())
                        for (let i = 0; i < raw.blocks.length; i++){
                            raw.blocks[i].type = "unstyled"
                        }
                        let newContent = convertFromRaw(raw)
                        newEditorState
                        const newState = EditorState.push(state, newContent, "change-block-type")

                        setState(newState)
                    }} />
```

Which worked except typing ended up being reversed on input after that, which was very confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the [`stripPastedStyles` option](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor/#strippastedstyles) is what you're looking for:

> Set whether to remove all information except plaintext from pasted content.
>
> This should be used if your editor does not support rich styles.
>
> Default is `false`.

Answer (score 3):

**Another interesting find:**

The **[`handlepastedtext` option](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor/#handlepastedtext)** can help to remove formatting that is not enabled within your editor.

Use it like this

```
<Editor
    // ...
    handlePastedText={() => false}
/>
```

Doing this, will for example keep bold text, headings, links, images etc which are enabled within your RTE, but will remove unrequired background styles, font-styles, etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice feature, but seems like it only works for inline styles, but not for block styles.